# Effect of Surge, EFT events on Current Transformers

Tags: current-transformer

I have an on board, Current transformer with ratio 1000:1.  The inputs are likely to face surge and EFT events ( 4kV level). Would like to know the behavior of CT. Will it just let through the surge, EFT voltages or will it attenuate in the secondary side?

Comment: I would like to verify the turns ratio.  Are you measuring a very large  current or a very small current?  What is the voltage across the primary of the CT?

Comment: How fast is this transient? What is the inductance of the transformer?

Comment: Most small current transformers will saturate above their design limit and the output will not go up much beyond their upper limit. But you can add a zener or some other diode based clipping circuit to protect things down stream.

Comment: Using CT07-1000,https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/192/CT07-1003158.pdf. Transient is standard 4kV EFT and 4kV surge as per IEC 61000 Specifications